# Upgrading to v3.0 - found more issues

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I have updated from Highcharts 2.3.5 to Highcharts 3.0 and found some problems:

1) When zooming in on the left/right side of the chart - it sometimes shows xAxis scale
offset -2, -1 OR 10, 11

See image attached:

[image]

Comment: i have this sort of issues when in drill down or chart redrawn may be cause due to some cahe issues .

Comment: Have you tried to set minPadding as 0 ? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minPadding

Comment: I tried using minPadding/maxPadding - did not work for me :(

Comment: Would be helpful if you will share your source code